# Several GET Methods in ASP .NET WEB API causing 500 when sending array using URI

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP .NET WEB API, I want to use the following methods:

```
        [Route(""), HttpGet]
        public IDictionary<int, string> GetAll()
        {
            //doSth
        }

        [Route(""), HttpGet]
        public IDictionary<int, string> GetSpecificOnes([FromUri]IEnumerable<int> carsIds)
        {
            //doSth
        }
```

When requesting the second one using angular, I get the following exception:

```
angular.js:12011 GET http://localhost:12345/_api/cars?&carsIds[0]=1&carsIds[1]=2&carsIds[2]=5 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I think the problem is, that I have two GET-Methods without a route. But I don't need one. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to define a route, like you say, as long as the GET methods in the controllers have different signatures and parameterlist.

The problem in your case is that you call the method the wrong way.

Either change the parameter name in the api method to `carsIds` or change the angular HTTP query string to `?ids[0]=1&ids[1]=2&ids[2]=5`

Comment: Okay, is there also a way to keep the link like it is built? Because I have no option to change it. Can I adjust my API to handle the link?

When I try to get the array as parameter `{carIds: carIds}`, I get:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: ' carIds'.'`

Comment: @testiguy updated my answer. You were using wrong parameter name when calling the method

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. In the code, I got it right. But still a problem when both functions I mentioned are implemented. When I delete one of them, it works.